# Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction int C# and MySql DB

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I develop a programe use c# Framework2.0  and Database is mysql.
I use transaction but always has error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Rollback()

Here is some of source code:

```
 try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                MySqlTransaction myTrans = connection.BeginTransaction();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = myTrans;

                try
                {

                   string sql ="XXXXX";
                   command.CommandText =sql;
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   sql="yyyy";
                   command.CommandText =sql;
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   .........

                  myTrans.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    myTrans.Rollback();
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileHelper.WriteLog(ex);
        }
```

I check the sample from:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqltransaction.html

The source code should be ok.

The error said the **connection seems close already.**
I think use Using() should be ok. it will close automatically.

Can Some help me with this?

Comment: Where is the `connection.Close()` command?

Comment: use using() will auto close connection

Comment: Instead of that, Try closing the connection manually by using `connection.Close()` , similar to the sample you are referring to.Auto Close connection doesnt seem to be a good practice.

Comment: What kind of excepion are you getting before the rollback? What is the error message? (By the way don't use `throw ex`, just `throw`)

Comment: @Khan I am curios to know where you have read this information about to NOT use the using statement (and in particular in reference to MySql)

Comment: I write ex to log file. the log show "System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Rollback()"

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger and follow this code to see where it throws the exception, also check the InnerException property. As written above there is no closed connection if the throw happens at the Rollback point. (Check Connection.State property just before the Rollback)

Comment: @Steve, Thanks you reply ,I have a big problem is that this problem only occur in production server which we don't have access to visit.My local works fine. my colleague PC also works fine. That's why hard to find the reason.

Comment: Do you have any InnerException? It seems a very strange behavior. When running locally do you have the exception and you handle it correctly or you don't have any exceptions? If locally you don't have exceptions then try to trigger one yourself. Another possibility is a different version of the MySql Connector. (And do you have the option to upgrade to Net 4.o?)

Comment: @Steve ,Many thanks your reply. my Local works fine. The production need Net2.0, We cannot to update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I find the solution .

The MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout default is 30 seconds.

maybe the server is old and data is big.
so timeout

so show error

> Connection must be valid and open to rollback transaction

Just Set `MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout=1200`

this one can work fine.

it's really hard to find the root cause.

Comment: this is wrong explanation i checked this. i do not know the real reason but this is wrong I'm sure.